# Кастомизация списка

Tags: java, android

Как можно сделать список чтобы был похож на этот?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> date = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(ar1.length);
Map<String, Object> map;
for (int i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++) {
 map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("name", ar1[i]);
date.add(map);
}
String[] from = {"name"};
int[] to = {R.id.n3};
SimpleAdapter ad = new SimpleAdapter(Stop1.this, date, R.layout.test3, from, to);
lv1.setAdapter(ad);
```

Вот так я заполняю тут только 1 массив как сделать так чтобы из двух массивов заполнялось одно справа как бы часы а второе слева минуты как на картинке

Comment: Можете уточнить вопрос. Что за именно вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Я хочу сделать такой список, только не знаю как

Comment: Я уже знаю как кастомизировать listview но он заполняется только одним массивом а тут я понимаю из двух заполняется

Comment: Вы должны создать свой ArrayAdapter с собственной разметкой если вы используете `Listview`

Comment: `ar1` это массив только с часами?

Comment: да я ток пытаюсь сделать n3 это textview в который выводится есть ещё второй textvew который надо помещать минуты

Comment: Ну так создайте массив с нужными вам минутами. А дальше вставьте в ваш `map`

Comment: Можете привести пример а то я что-то пытался не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 // как массив заполните это на ваше усмотрение
    int minutes[] = new int[12];

    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> date = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(ar1.length);
    Map<String, Object> map;
    for (int i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++) {
        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("name", ar1[i]);
        map.put("minutes", minutes[i]; date.add(map);
    }
    String[] from = {
            "name",
            "minutes"
    };
    int[] to = {
            R.id.n3,
            R.id.minutes
    };
    SimpleAdapter ad = new SimpleAdapter(Stop1.this, date, R.layout.test3, from, to);
    lv1.setAdapter(ad);
```